# NodeJS Mongoose record.save TypeError

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a small REST API on NodeJS with Express and Mongoose and am running into a TypeError I can't seem to resolve.

Express Router and Mongoose are as follows:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();
const querystring = require('querystring')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const iptvSchema = new Schema({
  appName: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  level: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  message: {type: String},
  meta: {
    ip: {type: String},
    mac: {type: String},
    campus: {type: String},
    venue: {type: String},
    room: {type: String},
    serial: {type: String}
  },
  tags: {type: Array}
});

const Iptv = mongoose.model('Iptv', iptvSchema)

router.route('/add/')
  .all(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("/add/ route")
    var query = Object.keys(querystring.parse(req.originalUrl))[1]
    console.log(query)
    var record = new Iptv(query);
    record.save(function(err) {
      console.log("save")
      if (err) {
        console.log("error")
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log("record created")
      }
    })
  })


module.exports = router;
```

The incoming request is a GET AJAX request from JQuery on the client. The `query` variable is verified as a correct JSON string extracted from the GET request:

```
{"appName":"iptv","userId":"0002026941e2","level":"info","title":"Amino Connected"}
```

The request errors out as follows:

```
 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {"appName":"iptv","userId":"0002026941e2","level":"info","title":"Amino Connected"}
at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:222:24)
at model.Document (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:67:20)
at model.Model (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:48:12)
at new model (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3785:13)
at /Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/model/iptv/router.js:31:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/jeremylo/Documents/dev/log/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `req.originalUrl`? It seems to contain incorrect values for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are passing a JSON string not a JSON Object, you will need to parse it to JSON Object before creating your record

replace

`var record = new Iptv(query);`

with

`var record = new Iptv(JSON.parse(query));`

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support JSON.parse(), which is defined in ECMA-262 5th Edition (the specification that JavaScript is based on). Its usage is simple:

```
var json = '{"appName":"iptv","userId":"0002026941e2","level":"info","title":"Amino Connected"}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.appName);
```